# Can The Collector Achievement in Call of Duty Black Ops Zombie Mode be unlocked as a group?

Tags: achievements, call-of-duty-black-ops, cod-black-ops-zombies

For the achievement in Call of Duty: Black Ops:

> **The Collector** - In Zombie mode, buy every weapon off the walls in a single game.

I am wondering if it can be unlocked collectively as a group buying all of the weapons or do you have to buy them all on your own (as 1 player).

It would make a big difference in the strategy to take in order to get the achievement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Trophies can be unlocked by a group or in solo.

It's normally best to buy all weapons by a group to unlock this trophy, to achieve this trophy effectively, follow this method:

- Be fair when opening doors, each player should take turns to spend their points when opening doors.
- Be prepared to gain many points before going out to buy all weapons.
- When ready to buy all of the weapons, use a grenade on a group of zombies (when near to end of a round) and make them legless which will leave you precious time to save running around to buy all weapons (including you and your friends/team mates to spend points towards the doors).

You may need about at least `10,000` roughly to spend on doors, and at least `12,000` to `15,000` (from what I remember ages ago). Which comes a total of between `22,000` to `25,000` points.

The Collector trophy does not require upgraded weapons or weapons from the mystery box.

---

This may be quite hard to achieve unless you have a good motivation of escaping and surviving from a large swarm of zombies and also taking them down, be sure to make good use of your grenades for high points when used against a swarm of zombies!

---

**Optional:** If you may want to test your luck, you can use the mystery box for a good, powerful weapon like the Alien/Ray gun could wipe out a lot of zombies in a few shots (better when upgraded) which will make you *kick ass*!

**Tip:** Don't camp. :)

Comment: Thanks, I unlocked this with a group, even though we had bought all the weapons off the walls it did not unlock until I bought each one myself though. For anyone trying this I would suggest to build up some cash once you've unlocked all the doors, make a crawler zombie, then you can easily run around and collect what you need.

Comment: Yes, exactly my points. Congratulations on the achievement. ;)